# When to choose ZoH method over Tustin in Discrete design?

Tags: digital-filter, block-diagram

Hey guys I am kinda confused as to which method to pick from, in terms for a digital filter. Which method is appropriate for this application and how did you come to pick it?

I want to convert a continuous Filter I already made into a discrete one. I have started it with adding a ADC at the input and wanting a analog output will be using a DAC at the output.

Having a Continuous Filter (H(s)) and having a block diagram of this: The circle is the summer(+|-)
[image]

Here is what I think about using either method

Tustin:

[image]

ZoH:

[image]

Why am I getting so confused on this? I know the ZoH method includes the delay from the DAC and Tustin is just a straight up conversion from S->Z domain. I can't wrap my head around which one to use as I always think when using the ZoH method is just repeats the DAC twice as a DAC will always be there.

Comment: Why does your top diagram show ADC and DAC when it is continuous (presumably the analogue world)?

Comment: How can the ADC output (digital) be summed with the DAC output (analogue)?

Comment: It was done late at night, was overlooked. Fixed